# Regex Extract First all CAPS word from lines containing Dollar Signs

Tags: regex, extract, uppercase

I have printouts with hundreds of lines, some containing stock symbols in CAPS that I'd like to extract, e.g.

STOCKS OPTIONS SYMBOL GROUPS WORKING
$14,489.60
$14,489.60 Mark WMT D
72%
($24.00)
$45.00 ($153.00) T
2 opt
$500.00 MSFT
100 Sha

I'd like to extract:      WMT   T   MSFT 
using online regex testers such as    https://regexr.com/
I spent hours trying expressions such as the following, but no luck yet to just extract just the symbols and none of the other text
$.+[A-Z]\w\s

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract from the sample data above?  What is your programming language?

Comment: I'm just using online regex testers then paste results into javascript where I just use the symbols separated by either spaces or commas.  I also use the list of symbols elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a programming language so I'll assume PCRE:

**regex**

```
^.*\d+.*?\K\b[A-Z]+\b
```

**data**

```
STOCKS OPTIONS SYMBOL GROUPS WORKING
$14,489.60
$14,489.60 Mark WMT D
72%
($24.00)
$45.00 ($153.00) T
2 opt
$500.00 MSFT
100 Sha
```

The extracted data is WMT, T, and MSFT

https://regex101.com/r/N2shwC/1

In English:

Find every line with digits and capture the first sequence of all capital letters surrounded by word boundaries.

Comment: Yes, this highlights the symbols exactly right in regex101 but I don't know how to make the list afterwards.  In https://regexr.com/ it does not highlight the symbols, but there I would chose Tools > List > $&  to get the list.  You got me going on the right path, though.  I really appreciate your help.  Thanks.

Comment: @TonyT In regex101 you can click on "Code Generator" at the bottom of the left-hand navigation if you need programming assistance. regexr.com is child's play compared to regex101.

Comment: That is really neat seeing generated code in all those languages!  Can I use the Function List on the left to list the symbols in regex101? What expression would I have to place on the line to get those symbols?   And for my curiosity to play with regex101 substitutions what would the regex expression look like to extract ALL BUT those symbols above?

Comment: @TonyT #1 https://regex101.com/r/M78RQ8/1

Comment: @TonyT #2 I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: The List and $0\n is exactly what I needed.  I am thrilled!  The #2 was my curiosity if there is a simple way in regex to negate everything.  Not important and I have lots to study now with the help and solutions you gave me.

Comment: @TonyT What do you mean by negate everything? You wish to remove the stock symbols from your original text? Regex does two things and two things only: replacement and extraction. Pick the correct action to achieve your desired goal.

Comment: No, to remove everything  EXCEPT the stock symbols.  I should not have distracted this thread.  I was only curious if there is a "global NOT" in regex to do just the opposite if one knows the expression that did the original intent.

Comment: @TonyT Sure, that's replacement (substitution). https://regex101.com/r/r6x4ek/1

Comment: Ah.  Exactly!  Thank you once more. I got everything answered now and have all results I was looking for.

Comment: @TonyT You're welcome, and fyi regex negation is notoriously difficult so your "global NOT" concept is impossible. You craft the regex for your data and choose whether you can extract what you need or get rid of everything you don't need. There is no "one size fits all"